# How to initialize useState from useSelector

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

I want to only showModal if userDetails?.needUserDetails === true.
I am trying to initialize useState from useSelector, but I can see that it starts off as null.
I also tried to pass in default parameter into showModal and also tried useEffect() to initialize setShowModal(userDetails?.needUserDetails)

```
const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.users.userDetails);
const userDetailsLoading =  useSelector((state) => state.users.userDetailsLoading);
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(userDetails?.needUserDetails);

return ({userDetailsLoading ? (
        <Spinner>
      ) : (
        <ShowModal
              showModal={showModal}
              needUserDetails={userDetails.needUserDetails}
              setShowModal={setShowModal}
            />
)
```

```
const ShowModal = ({
  needUserDetails,
  showModal = needUserDetails,
  setShowModal,
}) => {
  return (<Modal visible={showModal} onDismiss={() => setShowModal(false)})
}
```

What is the best approach to initialize useState from useSelector? Should this be avoided? What are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your initial state `state.users.userDetails.needUserDetails` is not set.
So you basically do everything right, but your initial value is not set.

Ok, so initially your `userDetails?.needUserDetails` will be set to null as you didn't fetch the `userDetails` yet (if it is always the case, then you probably even don't need to pass initial value). Once it is received your component will be rerendered as `useSelector` will trigger it. And we can useEffect hook, listening to `userDetails?.needUserDetails` to set the value

Oh, ok try following code, you also can remove strict equality, if you don't need it:

```
const userDetails = useSelector((state) => state.users.userDetails);
const userDetailsLoading =  useSelector((state) => state.users.userDetailsLoading);
const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(userDetails?.needUserDetails === true);

useEffect(() => {
     setShowModal(userDetails?.needUserDetails === true)
}, [userDetails?.needUserDetails])

return ({userDetailsLoading ? (
        <Spinner>
      ) : (
        <ShowModal
              showModal={showModal}
              needUserDetails={userDetails.needUserDetails}
              setShowModal={setShowModal}
            />
)
```

Comment: state.users.userDetails.needUserDetails is getting fetched from the backend, and doesn't get set until userDetailsLoading = false

Comment: @JTEA then you will get `userDetails.needUserDetails` equal to null initially.

Comment: @JTEA I have just updated an answer, useEffect should help

Comment: Dmytro Krasnikov, Thank you so much, It is working.